# How to use Python's BeautifulSoup html parser to get img tag src with 2 'src' attributes

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html5-img

I have HTML pages that contains image tags with 2 'src' attributes, and I want to use BS to extract the first 'src' and not the second 'src'.

For example:

When I use BS as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = <img class="lazy" src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/dog-puppy-on-garden-royalty-free-image-1586966191.jpg?crop=1.00xw:0.669xh;0,0.190xh&resize=980:*"                        src="https://www.mdf.qa/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/800x800/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/b/l/black_2.jpg"/>

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
bs_images = soup.find_all('img')
for bs_image in bs_images:
   attrs = bs_image.attrs
   image_path = attrs['src']
```

The path I'm getting is the second src "https://www.mdf.qa/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/800x800/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/b/l/black_2.jpg" but I need the first src - https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/dog-puppy-on-garden-royalty-free-image-1586966191.jpg?crop=1.00xw:0.669xh;0,0.190xh&resize=980:* .

Answer (score 0):

It seems that BeautifulSoup is rewriting second src on the top of the first so the first src is not stored anywhere. I would sugest using regex for this problem.

```
import re

html_doc = '<img class="lazy" src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/dog-puppy-on-garden-royalty-free-image-1586966191.jpg?crop=1.00xw:0.669xh;0,0.190xh&resize=980:*"                        src="https://www.mdf.qa/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/800x800/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/b/l/black_2.jpg"/>'

bs_images = re.findall('<img[^<>]+>', html_doc)
for bs_image in bs_images:
   image_path = re.search('src="([^"]+)"', bs_image).group(1)
   print(image_path)
```

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/VVcrZi/1/) is the link to src match. With re.search we only get first match (with findall would we get all matches).